# Selenium's Webdriver.execute_script() returns an empty list while Chrome dev tools return a populated list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium's Webdriver.execute_script() to get a list of elements from Reddit's homepage. (Before you recommend PRAW: Reddit is not actually what I want to get elements from, I'm just using it as an example.)

Even though my executed script works fine when I run it in Chrome's dev tools console, Selenium's method only returns an empty list, which should be populated with the title elements of Reddit posts.

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#Path to the chromedriver is definitely working fine.
path_to_chromedriver = 'C:\Path\goes\here\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
url = 'http://www.reddit.com/'

browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get(url)

code = 'document.getElementsByClassName("title may-blank loggedin")'
content = browser.execute_script("return "+code)


if len(content) == 0:
    print content
else:
    print len(content)

browser.quit()
```

I've also tried using the webdriver.set_script_timeout() and webdriver.set_page_load_timeout() methods.

Example of the target element:

```
<a class="title may-blank loggedin" href="/r/IAmA/comments/2necex/i_am_joel_hodgson_creator_of_mystery_science/" tabindex="1">I am Joel Hodgson, creator of Mystery Science Theater 3000, why don't you come at me?</a>
```

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript to get these elements and not inbuilt Selenium methods?

Comment: @Arran  `browser.find_elements_by_class_name('titlemay-blankloggedin')` also returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript you use with `execute_script` should work.

However, as the class `loggedin` suggests, **no element will match the `loggedin` class unless you are actually logged into the site.** When you start a new Selenium instance, it is not logged in, so you won't find any element with the `loggedin` class. Edit your code to remove `loggedin` from your `getElementsByClassName` call and you'll get a list of matched elements.

It does not matter whether you use `execute_script` or `find_element...`. No elements will match the class `loggedin` until you are logged in. This being said, although sometimes there are excellent reasons to use `execute_script` to find elements, I don't see a good reason to use `execute_script` *in this case* so I'd suggest something like

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.title.may-blank')
```

without the `loggedin` class. This will return all elements that have the `title` and the `may-blank` classes.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems.

Don't use JS to find the elements, that's the entire opposite to the point of Selenium.

Secondly, you have some misunderstanding behind what CSS selectors & Class name selectors are.

Thirdly, coupled with the above, your JS script is not a CSS selector. `getElementsByClassName` is very different, it will just return you what matches *all* of those classes.

Fourthly, in your comment you've bunched up the class name together. I assume this is because having spaces in there would have thrown a Compound Class error. This is correct and should have pointed you to the first three problems above. Now you've mushed them all into one string, it now no longer even relates to the original code you had - it would only return elements who had `titlemay-blankloggedin` as their class (obviously, none!).

Solution? I'd suggest using Selenium for what it's meant for and the locator strategies it has built in.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.title.may-blank.loggedin')
```

(The selector can be made a little less brittle, but I've done it on purpose so you can see the effect).

The `.` in CSS selector will work as an **and** operator (an anchor element that has a class of `title` **and** a class of `may-blank` **and** a class of `logged-in`.)

Comment: Thanks @Arran, works perfectly! Hopefully it works for my target webpage as well. Do you know why my JS didn't return a populated list?